# remove an embedded document in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a projects model with just a name field and in it also the embedded relation to line_items.
      class Project
       include mongoid::document
       field :name
       embeds_many :line_items
      end

```
  class LineItem
   include mongoid::document
   field :title
   embedded_in :project, :inverse_of => :line_items
  end
```

I suppose this is more of the mongo driver question: if I had such a document

```
db.project.find()[0]
      {
        _id : 123, 
        name : "housework", 
        line_items:[
         { title : "clean fridge", _id : 601},
         { title : "clean tub",    _id : 602},
         { title : "clean oven",   _id : 603}
        ]
      }
```

- 1) How do I update say the line item with id 601 in mongo console?
- 2) how do I delete it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Current Mongoid (2.0.0) allows:

```
@category = @list.categories.find(params[:id])
@category.delete
```

And the resulting database query/update looks like:

> MONGODB
>   test['lists'].update({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4d9522315569b11918000019')},
>   {"$pull"=>{"categories"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4d9523e05569b1191800001f')}}})

Also see the last example on http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/

Note, I tried variations on this that would have worked with ActiveRecord (@list.categories.delete(xx)) and those do not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

1/ Update :

```
pro = Project.first
line_item = pro.line_items.find(601)
line_item.title = 'new title'
line_item.save
```

2/ Delete :

```
pro = Project.first
line_item = pro.line_items.find(601)
pro.line_item_ids.delete(601)
pro.save
```

Comment: Thanks Shingara, but this is from Rails Console, not from the MongoDB console. Do you happen to know what the syntax is for mongodb?

Comment: for the delete is that the correct third line?  in most cases you won't know the ID of the embedded item, so you'd probably do a: line_item = pro.line_items.where(:title => "xxx").first and then a pro.line_item_ids.delete(line_item.id)

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

Update:

```
db.project.update( { line_items._id : 601 }, { $set : { line_items.title : "new title" } })
```

Delete:

```
db.project.update( { $pull : { line_items._id : 601 } })
```

Sorry about that, try it now?

Comment: Thanks Luckytaxi. The update works, but the remove actually removes the project(s) containing a line item with an id 601

Answer (score 0):

Try:

db.project.update({}, {$set: {line_items: []}});

to remove embedded documents, this will only reset the data inside it to empty but will still retain an empty object in the db which you can repopulate later on.

Comment: Hi Anand, thanks for giving an answer. I think I am more looking for deleting just one embedded record instead of deleting all the embedded records in a embeds_many association. But thanks anyways!